# Internet Explorer render issue (simple JS timer - window.setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, timer, timeout

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var theBar = createProgressBar(document.getElementById('progress-bar'));

    var value;
    function resetValue() {
        value = 0;
    }

    function showProgress() {
        value += 1;
        theBar.setValue(value);

        if (value < 100) {
            window.setTimeout(showProgress, 100);   
        }

    }
    window.onload=resetValue();showProgress();
</script>
```

--

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function createProgressBar(elem) {
        var div1 = document.createElement('DIV');
        div1.className = 'progress-bar-background';
        div1.style.height = elem.offsetHeight + 'px';
        elem.appendChild(div1);

        var div2 = document.createElement('DIV');
        div2.className = 'progress-bar-complete';
        div2.style.height = elem.offsetHeight + 'px';
        div2.style.top = '-' + elem.offsetHeight + 'px';
        elem.appendChild(div2);

        return {
            div1 : div1,
            div2 : div2,
            setValue : function(v) {
                this.div2.style.width = v + '%';
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

--

```
div.field input{
  height: 45px;
  width: 270px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.progress-bar-background {
            background-color: #D0D0D0;
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            overflow:hidden;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
.progress-bar-complete {
    background-color: green;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    top: -12px;
    left: 0;
}

#progress-bar {
    width: auto;
    height: 10px;;
    overflow:hidden;
    border: 0px black solid;
}
```

--

This snippet works perfectly under Chromer, Safari and FireFox.

The only issue is with Internet Explorer.

It seems to render as "half-full" and doesn`t execute anything.

Since I`m not that familiar with JS I have no clue what to start looking for.

Would appreciate some noob friendly advice.

Comment: Can you include enough CSS and HTML that we can actually run this in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this...

```
window.onload=resetValue();showProgress();
```

to this...

```js
window.onload = function() {
  createProgressBar();      
  resetValue();
  showProgress();
};
```

and you should be fine.

Remember...
"window.onload" is a property of the Window object ... and the value of this property should be a function that will execute automatically once the browser has loaded the entire DOM *AND* all the content (images, css, js, etc.)

This a NOT a good place to execute your stuff however -- you should use the event "onContentLoaded" but since it is not uniformly supported across browsers -- you should use a JavaScript library such as jQuery or Prototype or MooTools instead.

BUT -- of course if you're new to JS -- do NOT skim over it in order to get the pleasure of using these libs -- first get the real taste of what JavaScript is and what it is like to juggle with the browser incompatibilities -- only then you'll be able to appreciate the full potential of these libraries.

Comment: I think he also has to get the call the createProgressBar after the page has loaded successfully.  ALL DOM manipulation has to wait until the DOM is loaded - especially in IE.

Comment: of course -- you're totally right -- thanks for point that out

Comment: The code you posted seemed to fix the problem, thank you. Since I`m not familiar with JS one bit, what's a good starting point to learn from ? (books or online) Anything specific you could recommend? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Still not quite the right code since he has to save the value from createProgressBar, but it looks like Big_Bird has figured it out themselves now.

Comment: If you're starting JS -- read [this](http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Definitive-Guide-David-Flanagan/dp/0596000480) book -- i have yet to find a better book than this. Get the latest version of it.

Also, search for "JSCONF" on google -- you'd find a treasure of videos to enrich your JavaScript repertoire.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I see is that you shouldn't create the progress bar (or reference anything in the DOM) until the page has been loaded.  IE is particularly sensitive to this.  It looks to me like you're calling createProgressBar right when the javascript is loaded rather than after the page is loaded.

When I put your stuff into a jsFiddle and make sure that the code doesn't run until the page is loaded, it works for me in IE8.

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/CQqat/

Comment: So do I somehow delay executing or is there a way for me to check if page loaded and than run it?

Comment: You're already doing part of it with the onload handler.  Make one initialization function that you hook up to onload.  In that one initialization function, run all your initialization code including creating the initial progressbar, initalizing it and then starting it.

Comment: onload isn't ideal, but it will work in this case.  The javascript toolkits like jQuery and YUI make this easier.

Comment: I tried the jsFiddle you linked, seems to work fine. However when I go to my local machine it doesn`t. @greengit s answer seemed to fixed the problem.

Comment: Yeah, my comment to greengit was the last piece they needed.